# How can I change GameObjects location on the Hierarchy in [InitializeOnLoad] script type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I mean that if in the Hierarchy I have some objects that are children this specific objects to move them to the main root.

For example let's say I have this Hierarchy tree:

```
Cube1
 Cube1
 Cube1
 Cube1
  Cube1
Cube2
 Cube3
```

The first Cube1 and the Cube2 are in the main root.
Now I want to move the 3 childs of the main Cube1 and Cube3 to the main root:

```
Cube1
 Cube1
Cube1
Cube1
Cube1
Cube2
Cube3
```

The main goal is to move some specific objects from being children to the main root in the hierarchy. Like when I'm dragging a gameobject to the main scene root to do it by script.

Comment: Use the game object transform's SetSiblingIndex https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html

Comment: @Tricko I tried gameObj.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0); But still I don't see the objects in the main root of the scene. They are still children.

Comment: Sorry bout that. What I answered was for moving the game object as a child. If you want to change the hierarchy parenting, use `SetParent(target transform, false)`. The first parameter is the target transform, null if root. The second parameter determines if the transform should change. This is useful only if you are moving the game object from different spaces. Based on what you need, you can simply ignore the second parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you are looking for is:

```
transform.SetParent(null);
```